# sending a simple property in to a REST call

Tags: java, angularjs, web-services, rest

Can't we send a simple property instead of an object in to a REST call?

I tried to send a boolean for a PUT service call, and it gives me bad request error:
Following is my service call:

```
  virtualServerMonitoringProbeService.chainUnchainE1T1().update( {
                    id: $route.current.params.id,
                    cardId: cardId,
                    interfaceId: interfaceId
                }, true).$promise.then( function (resp) {
                        messageNotificationFactory.setNotification('success', resp.message);
                    })
                    ,
                    function (error) {
                        messageNotificationFactory.setNotification('error', error.data.message)
                    }
```

REST service implementation is as follows:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/v1/virtualserver/" + MODULE_NAME + "/{id}/tdmCapture/{cardId}/chainUnchainE1T1/{interfaceId}",
        method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public @ResponseBody
Object chainUnchainE1T1 (HttpSession session,  @PathVariable int id, @PathVariable int cardId, @PathVariable int interfaceId
        , @RequestBody boolean chained,HttpServletResponse response) {
    tdmCaptureServiceInterface.chainUnchainE1T1(cardId, interfaceId, chained);
    return ResponseHandler.sendSuccessResponse(SAVE_SUCCESS, response);
}
```

the interface doesn't get called.

Following is how the service call is made from client side:

```
  var chainUnchainE1T1Path = 'v1/virtualserver/monitoringprobe/:id/tdmCapture/:cardId/chainUnchainE1T1/:interfaceId';
      chainUnchainE1T1 : function() {
                return $resource(host + chainUnchainE1T1Path, {}, {
                    update: {
                        method: 'PUT',
                        params: {
                            id: '@id',
                            cardId: '@cardId',
                            interfaceId: '@interfaceId'
                        }
                    }
                });
            },
```

Comment: Is this Java? What is the client written in?

Comment: It's a Java service. We are using angularJs at the front-end

Comment: How is the client configured to call an URL like `"/v1/virtualserver/" + MODULE_NAME + "/{id}/tdmCapture/{cardId}/chainUnchainE1T1/{interfaceId}"`?

Comment: I think params array is for request parameters like '?id=id&cardId=cardId' but you have binded service to restful url, so from client you need to send it as one url without parameters.

Comment: @AlexChernyshev - can you please explain it? I didn't understand.

Comment: Can you change supported method for service from PUT to GET and try to call it from browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified my code to send and accept an object, instead of a simple value and then it worked.

```
 virtualServerMonitoringProbeService.chainUnchainE1T1().update( {
                id: $route.current.params.id,
                cardId: cardId,
                interfaceId: interfaceId
            }, {'chained' : true}).$promise.then( function (resp) {
                    messageNotificationFactory.setNotification('success', resp.message);
                })
                ,
                function (error) {
                    messageNotificationFactory.setNotification('error', error.data.message)
                }
```

REST service is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/virtualserver/" + MODULE_NAME + "/{id}/tdmCapture/{cardId}/chainUnchainE1T1/{interfaceId}",
    method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public @ResponseBody
 Object chainUnchainE1T1 (HttpSession session,  @PathVariable int id, @PathVariable int cardId, @PathVariable int interfaceId
    , @RequestBody Chained obj,HttpServletResponse response) {
tdmCaptureServiceInterface.chainUnchainE1T1(cardId, interfaceId, obj.chained);
return ResponseHandler.sendSuccessResponse(SAVE_SUCCESS, response);
```

}